# javax.json.JsonException: Unexpected Char=155 when creating jsonArray

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to do some parsing with JSON file simply getting the key and value from JSON and passing it into `jsonArray` then create hashmap from array.

My code works for most of the JSON files I encounters but doesn't work for one file (its huge and somewhat confidential). The error I'm getting is

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.json.JsonException: Unexpected Char=155
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readString(JsonTokenizer.java:168)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:302)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.nextToken(JsonParserImpl.java:158)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:183)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:151)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:184)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:152)
>   at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:127)
>   at parserUI.js2Properties(parserUI.java:173)

and my line 173 is this

```
JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
```

Do you have any idea what is causing this? The format of json are generally as this

```
[
    {
        "key":"aaaa",
        "value":"bbbbb",
        "description":""
    },
    {
        "key":"cccccc",
        "value":"dddddd",
        "description":""
    },
]
```

---

I found which line is causing the issue
its this
"value":"查看活动",
but if then created an identical line(shown below) to replace it, then it works
"value":"查看活动",

they are identical but one works and one doesn't
...can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you show the json?

Comment: I its a huge file and I can't really upload the whole thing but i've included the format in the original post

Comment: the exception clearly says that an unexpected character was encountered. so we either need to see the whole json or you should have a sharp look at it yourself to find this char.

Comment: Can you look if you have an char like `ASCII code 155 = ø ( Lowercase slashed zero or empty set )
 ( HTML entity = &oslash; )` in your JSON String?

Comment: @Jens seems like in json there are some scandinavian first/last names=)

Comment: @Jens ASCII ends at character code 127. 155 is in one of the extended code pages, which one however only the OP can know for sure.

Comment: @Tomalak I know that the ascii code ands at 127.

Comment: @Jens But still you claim that 155 encodes `ø`, which is something you cannot know.

Comment: @Tomalak That is a letter from the extended ascii code:  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/lowercase-slashed-zero-empty-set-ascii-code-155.html

Comment: @Jens There are many code pages, each of them defining the characters between 128 and 255 differently. It is impossible to know which character a code refers to if you only have the code.

Comment: @Gugg You can check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) if your json is syntactical correct.

Comment: Thanks guys, figured out

Comment: Don't look at your files in a text editor. Look at them in a hex editor. Write down the byte sequences you see and compare. That's the only way to figure it out (because that's how Java will see the file).

Answer (score 0):

There might be special characters or hidden characters or non printable unicode characters which might be there in input. Try to remove these type of characters with regex and then try.

Comment: That's a bad suggestion because the OP's files may very well be okay. Messing about with regex does not solve the problem and should be considered a measure of last resort (as in *"I receive broken files from a service I cannot fix."*) In any other case regex should not be used.